# Assigning a url to a string in singleitemvew.java

Tags: android

How to assign URL to a string. Should I use geturl() method?
In my activity I did it for the textview that retrieve data from parse.com like this
Created a textview object

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.I'd.text);

txt.setText(description);
```

Where

```
String description = intent.getStringExtra("desc");
```

How to do the same thing for URLs

Comment: instead of desc use url, that will work.

Comment: @NigamPatro But it's not a single file to give the url directly. There are various files

Comment: @NigamPatro Here have a look pleasehttp://stackoverflow.com/q/34131111/5524159

Comment: Mean, which URL, and where to set?

Comment: @NigamPatro To set it to file_url

Answer (score 0):

To assign a URL which is coming through intent, you just write `String url=intent.getStringExtra("key");` and it will assign the URL to the string.